# Geometric and Algebraic Multiplicity. Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Could someone please provide a thorough proof of why the geometric multiplicity of an
eigenvalue cannot exceed its algebraic multiplicity. Thank you.

Comment: The proof depends on what exactly your definition of "algebraic multiplicity" is

Comment: The algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue λ of A is the number of times λ appears as a root of pA, in this case

Comment: If geometric multiplicity is $a$, construct a basis using the $a$ corresponding eigenvectors, and rewrite the matrix using that basis. What does this matrix look like? What is its characteristic polynomial?

Answer (score 3):

One proof is as follows. Let $\lambda$ denote an eigenvalue of the $n \times n$ $A$ with multiplicity $k$. Let $x_1,\dots,x_k$ denote a basis for the eigenspace associated with $\lambda$.  Extend this list to a basis $\mathcal B = \{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ of $\Bbb C^n$. The matrix of $A$ relative to this basis is given by
$$
[A]_{\mathcal B} = \pmatrix{\lambda I_k & B\\ 0 & C}.
$$
Now, show that $\det(xI - A) = p_A(x) = p_{[A]_{\mathcal B}} = (x - \lambda I)p_C(x)$.  It follows that $(x - \lambda)^k$ is a factor of $p_A(x)$, so that the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ is at least $k$, as desired.